# Can a frozen turkey be "fresh"?

Tags: turkey

In the US, turkeys labelled "fresh" [can't be held (by the retailer) below 26F](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/wps/portal/fsis/topics/food-safety-education/get-answers/food-safety-fact-sheets/poultry-preparation/food-safety-of-turkeyfrom-farm-to-table/ct_index/!ut/p/a1/jZHBboJAEIafxuO6a7FGeyMkjdIKNaYVuZgFZ4EUGLI7lNKn71ZPNNq6c9qZ78_M_MNjHvG4lh9FJqnAWpY__3h2EBsxmyw84YeLyaNYBW-b8MnzxHx7b4H9H0Dg3Ki_8lzxn96_ocGdXnvrjMeNpJwVtUIeZUBM1qYDbXikEI_MSAXUMyVTYiYHIFtosC1J96zR0Eh98mRIo2LU6nfolcbKanXFCBnJpAQepXQo6iN88h2Ph1OKiY1V4GynSz9wRDj9DVyw8Qxc98kakZWYnG62d-vEmduNNSjQoMettumcqDEPIzESXdeNM8SshHGK1UhckuRoiEdDkjfVa_T17C5F8VLt5sb9BhWqxHo!/#8). The idea, as I've understood it, is that fresh turkeys aren't supposed to be frozen.

Well, one that I bought last year was definitely frozen in the middle. And yesterday, I was shopping for a thanksgiving turkey and all of the ones labelled "fresh" were suspiciously firm to the touch.

My question is, Will a turkey held at 26F freeze? Or at least become what a person might think of as frozen?

Comment: You do realize that 26F is 6 degrees below the freezing point?

Comment: @wumpusD'00m Well yes, but turkey meat infused with turkey goo may depress the freezing temperature, like salt does.

Answer (score 4):

Good Eats actually had something on this many years ago, as effectively turkeys aren't just water, so it doesn't freeze at the same point at water.

Copying/reformatting from the [Good Eats Fan Page transcript of Romancing the Bird](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season1/turkey/turkeytranscript.htm):

> **Chuck:** Just look at this. The USDA recognizes three distinctive market varieties of turkeys. The first is frozen.
>
> **Alton:** Meaning below 32 degrees?
>
> **Chuck:** Only turkeys cooled to zero degrees or lower can be labeled frozen.
>
> **Alton:** Well, uh, set me straight here, Chuck, but I thought 32 was the freezing point.
>
> **Chuck:** For water, sure. But the moisture in meat isn't just water. It's full of all manner of dissolved solids that effectively reduce its freezing point.
>
> **Alton:** You don't say. Okay. Thanks.
>
> **Chuck:** Oh, next at 1 to 26 degrees—although most manufacturers shoot for 24 to 26—are refrigerated birds.
>
> **Alton:** But frozen are so great, why bother?
>
> **Chuck:** Because refrigerated birds aren't as rock hard as frozen so they don't require as much thawing time. And grocers don't need as much freezer space.
>
> **Alton:** Is that it?
>
> **Chuck:** Oh, no, no, no. Fresh turkeys are a whole other thing. Fresh turkeys can never go below 26 degrees.
>
> **Alton:** But that's still below freezing.
>
> **Chuck:** Not in turkey.